# grequests.post() is returning None

Tags: python, grequests

```
>>> payload = {'a': 'b'}
>>> url = 'http://someurl/'
>>> req_ = [grequests.post(url, session=requests.session, data=payload)]
>>> r = grequests.map(req_)
>>> r
[None]
```

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a session instance rather than a session class:

```
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> req_ = [grequests.post(url, session=session, data=payload)]
```